# question about javascript imports. why are these imported as consts?

Tags: javascript, linux, import, gnome

Im wanting to try my hand at making a gnome-shell extesnsion for kali linux 2018.3
I have very little experience with java and i thought this would be a good chance to do some learning. so I used the gnome-shell-extension-tool --create-extension to create a basic template. In the .js file it created i noticed that the imports are different than i have used.  they are imported like this:

```
const St = imports.gi.St;
const Clutter = imports.gi.Clutter;
const Main = imports.ui.main;
```

my only experience is with imports like:

```
import java.awt.*;  
import java.util.blahblah;
```

im having trouble figuring out how to import anything else, the normal way i get errors about it not being found.  Could anyone give me a quick breakdown as to why this is so?

Comment: "In the .js file" Javascript isn't Java.

Comment: ok so why are the javascript imports like this.

Comment: well still dont have a solid answer to these imports.  what im thinking is its due to the way gnome is accessing extensions.  It looks like gnome extensions have a limited set of exports exclusive to gnome-extensions.  Can anyone verify that?  it looks like i will have to write a helper app to do anything major.

Answer (score 0):

Technically these aren't imports in Javascript.

Instead, in your example code, there exists global object `imports`, and are assigning it to constant variables.

You could just as easily write for your assignments:

`var St = imports.gi.St;`
`let Clutter = imports.gi.Clutter;`

This is very specific to your code, and not universally applicable to Javascript.

Initially, Javascript itself doesn't have imports. Instead there are syntactical sugar put around "modules" that provide similar functionality, that typically require a transpiler to convert it into valid javascript syntax.

There are a few flavors of how this is done, but the two common patterns are:

CommonJS

`const async = require('async')`

and ES6 Modules

`import async from 'async'`

Out of the gate NodeJS supported CommonJS format. As ES6 Modules were added to the standard, there were two ways to use them with NodeJS: 1. Use a tool like Babel to transpile your files from ES6 modules to CommonJS format, or 2: name your files with `*.mjs` extension.

Newer browsers now support ES6 modules, but typically web deployments use a combination of Babel and Webpack to standardize the output in the most compatible Javascript dialect.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Thank you alan for the explanation. I think this specific scenario is even more complex as Gnome is using gjs/seed for the js bindings, which is where the object for the few "imports" is coming from.  i think for my purposes im just going to write a helper app in python to do the few things i need.  Im sure i could dive into the transpiler option and come up with something, but my main reason for this project was to start learning js so i think i would be better off starting with standard type project.  looks like this project would mostly teach me stuff specific to gnome.